# Details on Free Authentication SMS in Firebase Blaze Plan

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working with Firebase Blaze plan for my project and I'm curious about the specifics of free authentication SMS in this plan. Unfortunately, I couldn't find this information in the documentation.

How many free authentication SMS messages are included in the Firebase Blaze plan?

Are there any limitations or conditions associated with the free authentication SMS quota in Blaze?

Comment: If you have questions about billing for Firebase products, reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming.

Comment: okay sorry!, but there is no other medium better than stack :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebase page on [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing):

> | Products | No-cost | Pay as you go |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Phone Auth - All regions | 10 SMS sent/day | Billed per SMS sent. See [current rates](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing) |

So it looks like you can currently send 10 SMS messages per day on the no-cost/free plan, and there doesn't seem to be any limit on the SMS messages that can be sent on the Blaze plan.

Comment: so imagine, i upgraded to blaze plan, and i sent 11 sms, so in this case 10 sms will become free and 1 will be paid? am i right?